# PowerShell Script A calls Script B then Close Script A while Script B is still running

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-5.0

I currently have a simple script (A) which uses Invoke-Expression to call script B.

```
#Call Script
$command = '\\BoxA\PowerShellScripts$\PS_CopyUIAutomationOutput.ps1'
Try
{Invoke-Expression $command }
Catch
{
Write-host "Error: "$_
}
```

But when it does this it keep script A running. What I want to do is script A calls script B and then script A is closed, while script B is still running logging is done to an shared path for script B, so I don't need to capture any error or logging in script A.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `exit` keyword:

```
Try
{Invoke-Expression $command }
Catch
{
Write-host "Error: "$_
}
exit
```

---

EDIT:

If you want it to exit directly after running the command just place it after the invoke expression like so:

```
Try
{Invoke-Expression $command
exit}
Catch
{Write-host "Error: "$_
}
```

Comment: Sadly not, it still runs the script B before closing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Stop-Process` and an automatic variable `$PID` to release the session of the Script A and close the PS window.

```
$command = '\\BoxA\PowerShellScripts$\PS_CopyUIAutomationOutput.ps1'
Try
{
Invoke-Expression $command
}
Catch
{
Write-host "Error: "$_
}
Stop-Process -Id $PID
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Start-Process`

```
Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell.exe -Argumentlist $Command
exit
```

this will start $command in a different process and continues to next line

regards,

Kvprasoon